# How to not accidentally ovewrite a class attribute in a Child

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class Parent:
    """ Class from some library"""
    def __init__(self):
        # how can I tell the IDE that the child class should not overwrite this?
        self.data = "don't touch this, some other method needs it"

    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

    def some_other_method(self):
        print(self.data)


class Child(Parent):
    """ My specified class, that implements the abstract method"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        # I did not look into all parents of all parents,
        # How to know that this is dangerous?
        self.data = data

    def method(self):
        print(self.data)

child = Child('hello')
child.method()
child.some_other_method()
```

Is there a way to mark the `data` attribute in the `Parent` class so that pylint (or a modern IDE) would warn about overwriting the attribute in the `Child`?
Or do I always have to check all attributes of all parents manually when using attributes in a child?

The only idea I have is checking for each attribute if it exists after initializing the parent before setting it in a child, but that also seems like some weird overhead to me.

`assert not hasattr(super(), "data")`

---

edit: To better explain what I mean, I am probably looking for something similar like the `abstractmethod` decorator for methods but for protected attributes instead.

For example, if I write something like this in my IDE:

```
class Parent:
    """ Class from some library"""
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self):
        pass


class Child(Parent):
    """ My specified class, that should implement the abstract method"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

My IDE complains about the missing implementation of `method` in the `Child`:

`Class Child must implement all abstract methods`

It **would** be cool to have something similar to mark attributes as protected like:

```
class Parent:
    """ Class from some library"""
    def __init__(self):
        @protected  # does not exist I am afraid
        self.data = 'do not touch this'


class Child(Parent):
    """ My specified class, that touches the data"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = 'I touch it!'  # should be marked with warning
```

For the linter/IDE to mark the overwritten protected attribute

Answer (score 2):

Not really, but what you can do is to prefix your attribute with `__` and will automatically will be rename when you're outside of the class. See code bellow

```py
>>> class P :
    def __init__():
        self.__data = "no overwritable"

>>> class C(P):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__data = "overwrited"

>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{'_P__data': 'no overwritable', '_C__data': 'overwrited'}
```

here your instance of C will have to data attribute, the one from the parent class P accessible through `_P__data` and the one from the child class C accessible through `_C__data`

In this way you don't always have to check if an attribute exists in a parent, but you can still access it if you really need it

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this yet, but it's not quite what I'd be looking for.
I somehow hoped there would be a decorator like "@protected" for the data attribute in the Parent or whatever that could warn the Child about overloading.

Similar to how in the opposite case, the IDE can warn about missing implementations of abstract methods in a Child.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as protected or private in python, this is the closest you can get unless you want to do some really dark and strange stuff.